# Recommendation on deploying a heavy Django + React.js web-application

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, web-deployment, web-hosting

*I got to build a **Django** application recently that has a database and performs some floating-point operations( biopython, alpha-shapes and similar algorithms on crystallographic data from the **database**) upon request from the **React.js** frontend.*

I was wondering what would be the best way to deploy something like this *long term* and how the two codebases would communicate with each other ( runs well on localhost as of now ). 
I've come across a few suggestions like digital ocean for django and firebase for the frontend, and heroku of course.

---

I have never, however, hosted a website that would go into production eventually, let alone two, and am a little at a loss as

1. to how the two codebases would communicate with each other,
2. how to preserve all the packages installed in django's virtual  environment in deployment,
3. how to transfer online the database to which the calls are made.

---

I would appreciate any pointer to resources to read up on or an architecture suggestion very much. 
Thanks a ton!

Comment: Django wise heroku is the way to imho. So your React parts are implemented in your Django Project? As for the packages installed, the hosting services cover all packages needed, no worries. If you use PostgreSQL, Heroku also offers a PostgreSQL add on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made a few apps using both `Django` and `React.js`, and to me the best approach is the following:

- "classic" backend with `django-rest-framework` and a database that suits you,
- calling your backend through your `django` API from the frontend.

A classic architecture for my projects looks like the following:

```sh
.
└── your_ambitious_project
    ├── frontend
    │   ├── public
    │   │   ├── favicon.ico
    │   │   ├── index.html
    │   │   └── manifest.json
    │   ├── src
    │   ├── package.json
    │   └── ...
    ├── backend_api
    │   ├── core_api
    │   │   ├── models.py
    │   │   ├── views.py
    │   │   └── ...
    │   └── backend_api
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── settings.py
    │       └── ...
    └── ...
```

Supposing you are going to use `Nginx`, the aim is to:

- make your `backend_api` accessible for your `React.js` frontend app,
- make user able to access your `frontend/public/index.html`.

For me, a typical `nginx.conf` file would look like this:

```sh
upstream backend_api { # so we can access django backend api from frontend
    server backend_api:8000;
}
# below: in dev environment only (for hot reloading)
# upstream frontend {
#   server frontend:1337;
#}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_ambitious_project;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend_api;
    }

    location / {
        alias /var/www/frontend/build/; # for production environment
        # proxy_pass http://frontend; # for dev environment (hot reloading)
    }
}
```

Then, you have to make your backend api accessible from the outside, so you will use for instance `gunicorn` to do so:

```sh
gunicorn siapi.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

For the frontend, in production environment `Nginx` will get the build of your project in the good location (after running `npm build`), else in dev environment you will have to run your server: `npm start`.

A few links you can get inspired from as I was:

- https://www.techiediaries.com/django-react-rest/
- https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/

Hope it will help you having some idea of how to combine the use of both frameworks!

Comment: This is super useful for starters, cheeky foldernames on point!
Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome! Took me some time to get something clean and maintainable (because it takes time to understand how everything is articulated), so I'm glad to see this project architecture sounds logical and not scary at first sight :)

Comment: Hi, KrazyMax I stuck in the MIME type error since somedays and today I posted a question in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73437331/mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supported-stylesheet-mime-type-and-strict-mime , will please help me